# What does "choke too loudly" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He wondered, as he did so, if they did not represent an unnecessary note of strain. Mrs. Barrows smoked only Luckies. It was his idea to puff a few puffs on a Camel (after the rubbing-out), stub it out in the ashtray holding her lipstick-stained Luckies, and thus drag a small red herring across the trail. Perhaps it was not a good idea. It would take time. **He might even choke, too loudly**.

Does [choke](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/choke_1?q=choke) in the example mean "cough"? It looks like since he is smelling a cigar for the first time it might make him cough so loudly that the neighbors would hear it.

[For context](http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm).

Comment: Sounds like it means "cough" to me.

Comment: Yes, it's talking about choking on the smoke, i.e. coughing. I guess he's trying to be quiet/secret for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True as said in the comments. *Choking* here seems 'coughing' **and also** [difficulty in breathing](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CHOKING) (dyspnea).

Coughing happens when someone tries a cigar (or the like) for the first time. [Here](http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/smoking-cessation/10-things-about-smoking-cessation-drugs.htm) are the symptoms that happen to a person when they smoke for the first time.

> When you learn to start smoking, it's not an easy process. It burns you. It **chokes you.** It makes you nauseous and dizzy, and while your head is spinning, you have a really bad taste in your mouth.